# Pass anonymous PFUser to Cloud Code in Parse iOS SDK

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, pfuser

I'm trying to secure a Cloud function in my Parse app. This function doesn't create objects or anything. It just calls an external API and returns the result. However, to make it secure I'm trying to create an anonymous user using the iOS SDK like so:

```
PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
print(PFUser.currentUser())
```

which outputs

```
Optional(<PFUser: 0x7fd3535570c0, objectId: new, localId: (null)> {})
```

So seems like the user is being created. But when I make a request using the `PFCloud` object, my parse function in Cloud gets a null user:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("<endpoint>", withParameters:[<params_dict>], block: {(result) -> Void in
    print(result)
})
```

Result on console log says `"user":null`. Does anyone know what I could be missing? Also, is this the best way to ensure requests are coming from my iOS client only, and not from some other source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your anonymous user is `null` because unless you save that user or an object related to it, it will not exist on the server. From Parse [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-anonymous-users):

> Anonymous users can also be automatically created for you without
>   requiring a network request, so that you can begin working with your
>   user immediately when your application starts. When you enable
>   automatic anonymous user creation at application startup, [PFUser
>   currentUser] will never be nil. **The user will automatically be created
>   in the cloud the first time the user or any object with a relation to
>   the user is saved. Until that point, the user's object ID will be nil**.

Also you cannot simply check if a request is coming from an iOS client. The whole point of a REST system is that server does not keep any state, it just responds to the requests from different sources. The sources have to send in their credentials (usually in a from of a security token which is issued by the server during a login) with every request. Server verifies the token is genuine and has not been tampered with before serving the request. Parse provides you with user authentication which makes it easy for you to verify that a logged in user is requesting something. You can then build extra security measures on top of that to make sure only certain users are allowed to access certain data.

Comment: Thanks Mo. Good point. I tried doing an incrementKey operation. But I'm a little lost since there's hardly any documentation with anonymous users. The user exists on the server after I did an incrementKey operation on the user. However, I couldn't understand when the user's session should be expired/when the user should be logged out? Also, I guess my question around that was more around the scenario where someone gets hold of my app id and client secret, and writes some iOS code to access my parse functions through anonymous users. Nothing is stopping that now it seems.What can I do about it?

Comment: Anonymous user is not a way to restrict access to a cloud function. Also Parse app id and client id are PUBLIC information and not secrets, so you should assume that your users can get them easily. You cannot restrict someone's access to your app features unless you ask them to somehow prove to you that they are genuinely your users (usually via some form of authentication) That is I am afraid the only way

Comment: I see. As for using authentication, is there anything else I can set on the anonymous user to check in my parse cloud code? An example would be hash of something, and check in my cloud code if that hash exists in the incoming user. That way any one trying to call my parse functions from outside my iOS app will need to at least dig in my code to find what that hash value is. Is there something like this I can do?

Comment: Well a hacker needs few minutes to crack that by simply looking at how your app communicates with Parse. I do not know the scope of your project or how strident your security policies should be. If it is not that important you better not to to bother with a few people who might abuse your system. Just get on with it and make your app ;)